# What is a good way to display a unit of measure after inputs in MVC3 views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We develop a lot of systems that have an input that should have a related text label after them for a unit of measure. e.g. Meter square, meter cubed, tonnes, ft cubed etc. I don't need to do anything clever like scale between units of measure. Just ensure that it is easy to update and  good practice.

Was looking for something that is reasonably automatic. That binds the unit of measure to the specific property. We have screens that mix 15 different units of measure with over 200 properties

I use ViewModels and Editor templates (although some things are hardcoded as dropdowns or texteditorfor etc so I could add classes).

Do any other people encounter this issue? I could just hardcode the text after the field in the view. Is there anything more graceful? Maybe an attribute etc?

Anyone have any thoughts on the best way to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [Measurement Unit Conversion Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23087/Measurement-Unit-Conversion-Library) on Code Project.

Comment: Looks interesting. Does it help with labelling units of measure in the actual view. I don't have any issues with actually converting at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display templates and more specific types.

For instance, create `Currency` class which is used to handle currencies. By doing so you know if it's cents, dollars or whatever and which currency the user uses.

More work, sure. But the code is more robust and it's easier to tell what unit should be used.

That's why are are using `TimeSpan` and not an `int` which could contain milliseconds, seconds etc.

Answer (score 2):

Graeme,

In your ViewModel, you could define your property with an attribute as such:

```
[Display(Name = "Unit - Meter square")]
public double Unit{ get; set; }
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing the point (which I could be!!), but I use this approach fairly widely on a variety of properties in various projects. Dropdowns would obviously be 'self-descriptive' in their 'text' element and thus wouldn't need the attribute in the same way, tho you may wish to decorate those in a similar but more generic fashion:

```
[Display(Name = "Unit of measure")]
public double Unit{ get; set; }
```

good luck

Comment: Was looking for something more automatic. That bound the unit of measure to the specific property. We have screens that mix 15 different units of measure with over 200 properties

Comment: ok, gotcha. will have a ponder (tho may be useful to add this comment and additional info to your question as it does make a HUGE difference to the requirement now)...

Answer (score 1):

My thinking is presently to add an attribute e.g.

```
[Unit(UnitOfMeasure.Mph)]
[Display(Name="Top Speed"]
public float TopSpeed {get;set}
```

Then do something either create a Html.UnitOfMeasureDisplay helper, or try to do something with EditorTemplates to automatically include it.