# Combining UIhint and additional metadata in MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating an attribute that I will use to provide additional information about the unit of measure of a property in an MVC 3 ViewModel. This follows me [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173810/what-is-a-good-way-to-display-a-unit-of-measure-after-inputs-in-mvc3-views) about the best way to accomplish this.

I have created a UnitOfMeasure attribute that passes additional information to the string template via the AdditionalValues metadata. Ideally I would like to create a Editor Template for UnitOfMeasure rather than adding it to the string editor template.

Is there anyway to tell a custom metadata provider to change the selected template? Effectively if it sees the UnitOfMeasure attribute on a property then I would like to also add UiHint("UnitOfMeasure") automaticallly behind the scenes. That way I would not have to add code for my UnitOfMeasure helper in the string editor template.

I should note that I don't want to use UiHint control parameters (unless it is the only option)

Thanks

Comment: graeme - someone marked you down for this question and rudely didn't say why. i've marked you back up to redress the balance!!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I noticed. I am happy to fix any issues with the post. If I missed that this is a dupe etc fine, happy to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have your custom attribute derive from UIHint:

```
public class UnitOfMeasureAttribute : UIHintAttribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public UnitOfMeasure(): base("foo")
    {

    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [UnitOfMeasure]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

or:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

and in both case in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
```

in the first case, obviously the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/foo.cshtml` custom template will be used whereas in the second the default string template.

Comment: That just sounds to simple :) ! Will test that now. Also just wondering what the purpose of IMetadataAware is. My existing Attribute just inherits from Attribute?

Comment: @GraemeMiller, the purpose is to add additional metadata (like this: `metadata.AdditionalValues["foo"] = "foo bar";`) that you could exploit in your custom editor template. If you don't need it, simply remove this interface, but since I saw you mentioning it in your question I thought you needed it.